# LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. (ReactiveMongoRepository)

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, reactor-netty

I'm using `ReactiveMongoRepository` with `Kotlin` and I'm getting this memory leak error from time to time:

StackTrace:

```
LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information. Recent access records: 
Created at: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:385) 
io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187) 
io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178) 
io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:115) 
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(NettyDataBufferFactory.java:71) 
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(NettyDataBufferFactory.java:39) 
org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:236) 
org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.encodeEvent(ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.java:174) 
org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.lambda$encode$0(ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.java:160) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:358) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) 
reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxConcatMap.java:476) 
reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442) 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250) 
com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.onNext(AbstractSubscription.java:155) 
com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.processResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:230) 
com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.tryProcessResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:185) 
com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoIterableSubscription.lambda$requestMoreData$1(MongoIterableSubscription.java:99) 
com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48) 
com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.handleGetMoreQueryResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:351) 
com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.access$600(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:56) 
com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:383) 
com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:356) 
com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:288) 
com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:84) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:530) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:142) c
om.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:463) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:440) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:745) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:712) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:582) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:255) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:214) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1100(InternalStreamConnection.java:78) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:702) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:687) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:582) 
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:255) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:214) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:285) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$800(NettyStream.java:69) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:344) 
com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:341) 
io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) 
io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1533) 
io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1282) 
io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1329) 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) 
io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) 
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) 
io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) 
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Some code:

```
  // REST
  @GetMapping("/global", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
  fun getAll(): Flux<PersonDto> {
    return personService.findAllCompanyIdNull()
  }

  // Service
  fun findAllCompanyIdNull(): Flux<PersonDto> = personRepository.findAllByCompanyIdIsNull().map { it.toDto() }

  // Repo
  interface PersonRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, ObjectId> {
    fun findAllByCompanyId(companyId: Long): Flux<Person>
  }
```

This error happens from time to time in my server.

I'm getting another error sometime, and. I'm not sure if it is related:

```
Callback onResult call produced an error com.mongodb.MongoException: Subscription has already been terminated at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.onError
```

My code is pretty simple and makes standard use of the API, Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: What's Spring Framework version?

Comment: id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.3"

Comment: Can you add `logging.level.reactor.netty=debug` to your `application.properties` and run with `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=paranoid` so that we have more information for the memory leak?

Comment: Hi, done and added the logs here https://gist.github.com/ramiloif/0194f6c248dfe9885b12e7da5ffc28aa

Comment: I would recommend you to open an issue and provide a reproducible example if it is possible.

Comment: opened issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1546

Comment: do you use sleuth 3? we had something similar memory leak issue when started to use sleuth 3 combined with reactive mongo (it can be switch off, but default is on)